# What is the selector should be used when applying .click() to an li element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Just learning `JavaScript`. I am having trouble with a simple menu. Right now, I just want the `div` class `.welcome` to have the class `.inactive-slide` attached to it (no, not a very useful thing, but I am just learning), but for some reason it is not working. My assumption is that my selector is not right (hence the general phrase in there now).

`JavaScript` code:

```
var main = function(){  "use strict";
    $(li element selector).click(function() {
        $('.welcome').toggleClass('inactive-slide');
   });
};

$(document).ready(main);
```

relevant css:

```
.welcome {
width: 1000px;
text-align: left;
margin: auto;
border-left: medium solid #000000;
padding-left: 20px;
}

.inactive-slide{
    display: none;  
}
```

Relevant HTML:

```
<div class="nav">
  <div class="container">
    <ul>
      <li id="port"><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Who We Are</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Pure Cause & Effect</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="welcome">
    <div class="welcometop">
       <h1>welcome</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
       <p>a bunch of words</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, here is the `JSfiddle` of everything: https://jsfiddle.net/royal_wisdom/bqr7ew9z/3/

Comment: Could you add your HTML as well so we can tell you how you select what?

Comment: Your fiddle works fine - that is once you [tell it to use jQuery](https://jsfiddle.net/bqr7ew9z/4/)

Comment: any valid DOM query selector can be used `.class-name`, `html-element` and `[attr='value']` are all valid examples. They can be chained too `.list li[class='selected']` for example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is correct. The only reason it isn't working correctly in `JSFiddle` is because you haven't added the `jQuery` reference. See exactly the same code working below (notice the additon of `jQuery` reference at the very top) :

```js
var main = function () {
    "use strict";
    $('.nav a').click(function () {
        $('.welcome').toggleClass('inactive-slide');
    });
};

$(document).ready(main);
```

```css
@charset"utf-8";

/* CSS Document */
 .wrapper {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:max;
    height:max;
}
body {
    background-color: #FFCE5F
}
.logoheader {
    color: #000000;
    min-height: 400px;
}
.imagecontainer {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 100px;
    width: max;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.nav {
}
.nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 28px 0 0 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid;
    border-bottom-color: #000000;
}
.nav ul {
}
.nav .container {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    width: max;
}
#port {
    color: #5a5a5a;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.welcometop {
    text-align:center;
}
.welcome {
    width: 1000px;
    text-align: left;
    margin: auto;
    border-left: medium solid #000000;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
.welcometop {
    text-align:center;
}
.inactive-slide {
    display: none;
}
.active-slide {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
 <title>Rippe Keane</title>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="logoheader">
                <div class="imagecontainer">
                    <img src="https://media.glassdoor.com/sqll/248681/rippe-keane-marketing-squarelogo-1392301668926.png" alt="We're good at this, we promise!">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="nav">
                <div class="container">
                    <ul>
                        <li id="port"><a href="#">Portfolio</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Who We Are</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Clients</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Services</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Pure Cause & Effect</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="welcome">
                <div class="welcometop">
                    
<h1>Welcome to Rippe Keane Marketing</h1>

                </div>
                <div>
                    <p>Accountability. It's a word that makes most marketers squirm; after all, the science of marketing is a "soft" one. Or is it? At Rippe Keane, we believe that the customer's experience with your brand can be managed in its entirety; carefully crafted and executed to not merely satisfy, but to captivate and inspire. To cater to wants your customers didn't even know they had.
                        <p>As part of our unique brand architecture and strategic planning process, we make it our business to know your business. Top to bottom, inside and out. We develop innovative solutions for nearly anything that affects your bottom line, from public relations and media services to business planning and operations.</p>We are meticulous. Insightful. Observant. We scrutinize. Collaborate.
                        <p>And we develop a solid foundation before moving on to the creative fun stuff.</p>All so your customers keep coming back for more.
                        <p>The results we deliver don't happen by chance. They happen by design.</p>That's "Pure Cause and Effect."</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </body>

</html>
```

Here's a `jsfiddle` example if you prefer (observe the addition of `jQuery` reference at the top left side of the page) : https://jsfiddle.net/z67ummw2/

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: By Zeus' beard, that was fast... Thanks for the help!

Comment: @RM3 Glad to help!!!

Answer (score 1):

You must include jQuery file before you doing your jQuery functions
In jsFiddle http://prntscr.com/8x404v it's there.

If you turn it on for jsFiddle your code starts working. Probably you executing your main function before including jQuery

Comment: Your answer could be a little more expansive, like the one above that added a working version, but I dont see why someone would downvote it. Its short and terse but its correct.

Comment: The down vote isn't required. This answer is correct, but, as mentioned by @somethinghere isn't expansive enough. +1